# Measuring memory usage of a web page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to measure the memory usage of my site with the memory section of the Timeline tab in Chrome developer tools.

At various points I hit the garbage can button to force a garbage collection.  The problem is the graph suddenly goes limp, and stops all measurements.  Eventually, after I start doing other things it starts measuring again, but I never see the exact spot / value on the graph where I hit the GC button.

[image]

The first two downward slopes start immediately after I hit the garbage collect button, and they later just sort of connect to a new current value after I've been working.

Question is:

Is there a way to force this graph to keep or start measuring?  Alternately, is there a simple way in JavaScript to `console.log` the current memory usage value?

As a related question, is there a way to point to a spot on the graph and see the exact memory usage at that point?

Comment: From the console, you can get the current memory usage with `performance.memory`.

Comment: Nice - thanks.  Would you mind adding that as an answer, @bfavaretto

Comment: @bfavaretto - also, any idea why performance.memory is giving me all zeros?

Comment: No idea, here is what it gives me for this page: `MemoryInfo {jsHeapSizeLimit: 793000000, usedJSHeapSize: 10000000, totalJSHeapSize: 17100000}`. I actually don't know much about it, or about the Timeline tool. That's why I just added a comment, there probably is a better answer...

Answer (score 5):

Timeline records events that happen on the renderer side. Each event record also has "memory usage" field. Timeline uses these numbers for the memory graph. So if there are no events for a time interval then memory graph shows nothing.

From the other side if renderer does nothing then the memory size doesn't change.

If you absolutely sure that you need memory data then you can setup a timer that does nothing.

For example you can execute in console `setInterval(function() {}, 1000);`
In that case Timeline will get timer event with the memory usage data and will draw the memory graph.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Unfortunately, for some reason once I hit the garbage collect button, it seems like the graph just completely stops responding - even with the `setInterval` in there.

Comment: sounds like a bug. Could you provide a link to the page or to the reduced test case.

Comment: What version of chrome are you using?

Comment: could you please try dev-channel or even canary version.

Comment: Canary version installs side by side with the other versions.